# 'decompression failed' error when downloading xlrd python package

Tags: python, xlrd

I get the 'decompression failed' error when downloading xlrd python package from the following link. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

I have downloaded python packages in the past but never got this error. Pls can someone tell me what may be the source of the error.

Comment: What tool is giving you that error? I was able to download and decompress the tarbal just fine.

Comment: I am trying to download it from the link on the website, not using any tool as such.

Comment: What is then giving you the error?

Comment: I am downloading it on my Mac. When I look at the downloads folder I see the 'decompression failed' error. This is the first time I see such an error when downloading python packages.

Comment: What browser is that? Safari? I used Chrome on Mac, and it the Mac Archive Utility decompressed it for me just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari appears to be broken for that link, I see the same error when I use that browser.

Either use a different browser (both Chrome and Firefox handle the file just fine), or use `curl` from the command line:

```
curl -O "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.0.tar.gz"
```

Comment: Call me crazy, but I thought "download" and "decompress" were quite independent concepts. Decompression failed when downloading???

Comment: @JohnMachin: Safari auto-decompresses the tarball on download, based on the file extension.